# html line-height with lowercase overlap

Tags: html, css

Once I increase the size of font. It will overlap to next line. Only happened on lowercase. Is there any way to solve?

[image: pic]

Comment: It's related to the `line-height`, not the `font-size`.

Comment: make `line-height: normal;` it will automatically adjust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Dork Face's answer is technically correct, let me add some more information which I think will help you find a more permanent solution to your problem.

Since overlapping started after increasing the font-size, it most likely means you have a line-height defined in pixels. Now, increasing line-height pixel size would solve the problem for now, but what if you increase the font-size again?

I suggest you define the line-height this way: `line-height:1.5;` or `line-height:2;`. It will be multiplied with your current font-size.

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp)

By the way, default value is `line-height:normal;` which should not give you overlaps on any decent font-family. You should look into that as well and remove unnecessary styles.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `line-height` like this.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <p style="line-height: 25px;">Some text.<br>new line here.</p>
    
  </body>
</html>
```